# Duplicated countdown timer after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
var secondsRemaining = 45;

function countdown(secondsRemaining) {
var  seconds = secondsRemaining;
if (secondsRemaining > 0) {
 $('.timer > div').html(seconds);
 secondsRemaining--;
} else {
 if (secondsRemaining == 0) {
  // Times up ....
 }
 }
setInterval(function() {
countdown(secondsRemaining);
}, 1000); 
}
```

I am running the function in the Document ready function with:

```
 countdown(secondsRemaining);
```

and also I run it again after I clicked for answer.
the problem is that I have 2 countdown timer now running simultaneously, new one that start from 45 seconds and the old one that continue from where it was.

Comment: And what is an expected behavior?

Comment: If you don't want two, don't call it again?

Comment: `setTimeout`/`setInterval` are inaccurate and should not be used for countdowns.

Comment: @Bergi So what should be used instead?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: A self-adjusting `setTimeout` loop measuring the actual time with `Date.now()`

Comment: Have you tried to change `secondsRemaining--;` with `seconds--;`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `clearInterval()`

First, store the interval id of the first `setInterval()`:

```
var secondsRemaining = 45;

function countdown(secondsRemaining) {
var  seconds = secondsRemaining;
if (secondsRemaining > 0) {
 $('.timer > div').html(seconds);
 secondsRemaining--;
} else {
 if (secondsRemaining == 0) {
  // Times up ....
 }
 }
myinterval=setInterval(function() { //myint now contains the interval id
countdown(secondsRemaining);
}, 1000); 
}
```

Now, when the user clicks, before setting up a new interval, cancel the first one with `clearInterval()`:

```
button.onclick=function(){
  //do stuff
  clearInterval(myinterval)
  setInterval(function() {
    countdown(secondsRemaining);
   }, 1000); 
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't really understand the way you have phrased the question seems to say that you intentionally want to start two time events, one when the document has loaded and the other when you click answer which are both outputting to the same element.

If the problem is you want it to have the output in two different elements then you could pass an argument of the element you could use:

```
countdown($('.pick-me'), secondsRemaining);
```

If you want to use the same element, then you could always clear the interval on each click and then set the interval for the new event, just got the update and seen Manishearths response so wont go into any more detail about it as that's probably the answer you are looking for.